# What does "power beamer" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The most important criteria a power beamer is judged by is the overall efficiency. The overall efficiency is determined by the electro-optical efficiency of the source, the opto-electrical efficiency of the photo voltaic cells and the optical setup in between these two components.
>
> **Source:** "[Power Beaming with Diode Lasers](http://www.dilas.com/gdresources/downloads/whitepapers/DILAS_SSDLTR_08_Power_Beaming_with_Diode_Lasers.pdf)"

What is a power beamer?

Comment: A power beamer would be a device for power beaming.  Note that entire reference is about power beaming.

Comment: In technical literature you're more likely to see it called ["inductive charging".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_charging)

Comment: *Power beaming* is a less formal phrase for "wireless power transmission": delivery of electrical power from a source to a destination location without stretching cables between the two points.

Comment: it seems to me that a brief scan of the article plus perhaps a few references to a dictionary would have answered your question.

Comment: I would keep this question open—not because the OP couldn't have found the information in the cited article, but because future readers may encounter the term in a context where adequate explanation is lacking; as far as I know, most general-reference dictionaries do not have an entry for  _power beamer_.

Comment: @SvenYargs - Isn't it obvious to the casual observer that it's a souped-up BMW?

Answer (score 1):

The mentionned source refers to an elevator using on-board solar cells to get the power required to ascend. The solar cells are either illuminated by solar light concentrated by a set of mirrors or by a "power beamer", i.e. a *high-power laser* located on the ground.

*The efficiency of light to electricity conversion is a critical factor, because it directly impacts on the elevator temperature, and therefore on the weight of embedded heat dissipation system*.

From Wikipedia [Space Elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator):

> **Powering climbers** Both power and energy are significant issues for climbers—the climbers need to gain a large amount of potential energy
>   as quickly as possible to clear the cable for the next payload.
>
> Various methods have been proposed to get that energy to the climber:
>
> - Transfer the energy to the climber through wireless energy transfer while it is climbing.
> - Transfer the energy to the climber through some material structure while it is climbing.
> - Store the energy in the climber before it starts – requires an extremely high specific energy such as nuclear energy.
> - Solar power – power compared to the weight of panels limits the speed of climb.[50]
>
> Wireless energy transfer such as laser power beaming is currently
>   considered the most likely method. Using megawatt powered free
>   electron or solid state lasers in combination with adaptive mirrors
>   approximately 10 m (33 ft) wide and a photovoltaic array on the
>   climber tuned to the laser frequency for efficiency.[2] For climber
>   designs powered by **power beaming**, this efficiency is an important
>   design goal. Unused energy must be re-radiated away with
>   heat-dissipation systems, which add to weight.